# Force same MAC address on multiple Bluetooth transmitters

Tags: macos, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to force the same MAC address on multiple Bluetooth transmitters/receivers in either software (Raspberry Pi) or hardware.

If so would this mean if a device paired to one, it would also be paired to the other?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible no because the whole point of a MAC address is that it is unique to each device to allow it to be identified. You may be able to set up the Pi to broadcast to multiple MAC addresses however if the devices need to be paired you would need a bluetooth transceiver capable of multiple connections.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've been doing some researching and found its possible to spoof a MAC address, but i think this will cause problems with data being sent to the wrong bluetooth transmitter. I'll set up a few Pis and see if it works